# App forgets region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = false

Tags: ios, swift

my App sometimes forgets the

```
region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = false
```

I set up a CLBeacon Region in my MainView Controller:

```
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var region:CLBeaconRegion!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: uuidString!)!, major: majorvar, minor: minorvar, identifier: "Beacon")

    // 2. setup locationManager
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;


    // 4. setup test data
    setupData()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    region.notifyOnEntry = true
    region.notifyOnExit = true

    region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = false


    // Request authorisation to track location

    if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways) {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }


    if (CLLocationManager .isMonitoringAvailableForClass(CLBeaconRegion))
    {
        print("OK")
    }
    else {
        print("Problem")

    }

    locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(region)
    locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

}
```

I call a push notification on `didEnterRegion` and `didExit` Region. It works fine. However after a certain time the App seem´s to forget the `notifyEntryStateOnDisplay=false`. Because it starts to fire the push notifications Enter and Exit every Minute or so while i´m in the Beacon Region.

Is it because I set the region in a view controller and not in the app delegate? Any ideas?

Many Thanks
Stephan

Comment: What is the state of your app when these notifications fire ? Foreground or background ?

Comment: Do you have the background mode enabled? Is this iOS 9?

Comment: Hi, it´s in background. And i´m testing on iOS9.3.4. The strange this is that it works in the beginning. And I can´t see anything that triggers it to change.

Comment: and yes background mode is enabled

Comment: Nobody any Ideas?